# Search in Windows Phone Store by developer name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm working on WP8 application and I want to add a button which is open the store and list my applications. Like this button in the Store: "More from Example". How can i make it, what is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
MarketplaceSearchTask moreAppsSearch = new MarketplaceSearchTask();
moreAppsSearch.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
moreAppsSearch.SearchTerms = "YOUR_DEVLOPER_NAME";
moreAppsSearch.Show();
```

This will open the store on phone with list of apps published by you